# Why .NET designer create code like this: Classes.Customer customer1 = new Classes.Customer();

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I use C#, .NET 4.5.1, VS 2013.

Can anybody explain me exactly and why, if I create a UserControl like that, with a property that contain another class:

```
public partial class CustomerSelect : UserControl
{
    public Classes.Customer Customer
    {
        get { return customer; }
        set { customer = value; }
    }
    private Classes.Customer customer;

    public CustomerSelect()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        customer = new Classes.Customer();
    }        
}
```

When I place this control on a Windows Form he generate that code in the designer:

```
Classes.Customer customer1 = new Classes.Customer();
this.customer1 = new Classes.Customer();
```

And below:

```
// 
// customerSelect1
// 
this.customerSelect1.Customer = customer1;
```

Why he create automatically a new Customer ? I try to change the initialization of the private property with = null, = new Classes.Customer(), removing my control, the code, adding again and I get always the same result.

Thanks if anybody can explain me what I understand wrong.

Comment: Sorry I removed first comment by mistake who say me about DesignerSerializationVisibility. Seem to be just the hidden arg to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior for a public property with both a getter and a setter that has a value at design-time that is not the [DefaultValue].  You have to tell the designer to not serialize the property and not display it in the Properties window:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
[Browsable(false)]
public Classes.Customer Customer
{
    get { return customer; }
    set { customer = value; }
}
```